# c++/qt how to have a global static variable

Tags: c++, qt

I want to store some values / variables so that I can change and read them in any class.

What I tryed so far:
I created a header file called "settings.h":

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
#define SETTINGS_H

#include <QString>

class Settings {
public:
    static QString OutputFormat;
};

#endif // SETTINGS_H
```

Now I included it in a class with:

```
#include "settings.h"
```

But when I try to set this variable:

```
Settings::OutputFormat = "mp3";
```

It will not compile with that error:

```
undefined reference to `Settings::OutputFormat'
```

What to do?
I need something like a settings class. Any class which
    #include "settings.h"
should be able to read the variable values and change them. The values should be global and shared between all classes which include this settings class.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/1413395) specifically.

Comment: You wouldn’t want a static anyway, and this should be a plain struct. Expose it via an “instance” static, a-la `qApp`.

Comment: @KubaOber Would be nice if you could add it as answer with some example code. (Sorry, I'm pretty c++ noob yet.)

Comment: If you plan to store the settings to a file (as word "settings" usually implies that in context of application programs), check out `QSettings`.

Comment: @hyde no, my settings are just for program runtime and should reset when restarting the program. however thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a "location" for this variable in a cpp file somewhere:

```
QString Settings ::OutputFormat;
```

And this is enough. Without a "location" in a source file, the compiler will not create the variable and it will be an undefined reference.

Comment: I created a settings.cpp file now and did it there. Thanks.